# Configuring Spring Boot Security to use a JWT as the access token and a regular token for the refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

So far I have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Value( "${spring.security.oauth2.jwt.keystore.password}" )
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Value( "${spring.security.oauth2.jwt.keystore.alias}" )
    private String keyStoreAlias;

    @Value( "${spring.security.oauth2.jwt.keystore.filename}" )
    private String keyStoreFilename;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory =
                new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource(keyStoreFilename), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(keyStoreAlias));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly and allows me to authenticate requests with a JWT token, but the payload I receive from a clientcredentialgrant or passwordgrant not only changes the access_token to JWT, but also the refresh token. Is there any way to have the access token be a JWT but not the refresh token?

Thanks,
Chris